# DataGridView.SelectionChanged event firing when BindingSource.SuspendBindings() turned on

Tags: .net, vb.net, bindingsource

In the following sample, I create a collection of objects and bind them to a DataGridView.  When the button is clicked, I .SuspendBinding, then remove all the records, then .ResumeBinding.  The DataGridView1_SelectionChanged event is fired when I remove { m_dataSource.RemoveAt(pos) } the selected row of the Grid.  Why is this?  I would think that .SuspendBinding() would stop any events from firing through to the grid.  If not, what is the point of .SuspendBinding()?

Thanx.

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
```

Public Class Form1

```
Private m_dataSource As New BindingList(Of BusinessObjects.Person)


Private Sub DataGridView1_SelectionChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.SelectionChanged

    Label1.Text = String.Format("SelectionChanged {0}", Date.Now.ToShortTimeString)

End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    LoadData()
End Sub

Private Sub LoadData()

    Dim tempPerson As BusinessObjects.Person

    tempPerson = New BusinessObjects.Person() With {.PersonID = 1, .FirstName = "a", .LastName = "b"}
    m_dataSource.Add(tempPerson)

    tempPerson = New BusinessObjects.Person() With {.PersonID = 2, .FirstName = "c", .LastName = "d"}
    m_dataSource.Add(tempPerson)

    BindingSource1.DataSource = m_dataSource

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    BindingSource1.SuspendBinding()

    Dim pos As Int32

    For pos = m_dataSource.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
        m_dataSource.RemoveAt(pos)
    Next

    BindingSource1.ResumeBinding()

End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`SuspendBinding()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.suspendbinding.aspx) does not stop events firing on the datagridview. It stops the *databinding* -- i.e. changes in the datagridview will not update the original datasource when binding is suspended.

Since the `SelectionChanged` event is completely independent of the data binding (it fires even when there's no databound source), it continues to fire even if the databinding has been suspended.

Are you specifically looking to stop the `SelectionChanged` event firing? In this case you can temporarily unbind the handler, e.g.

```
RemoveHandler DataGridView1.SelectionChanged, AddressOf DataGridView1_SelectionChanged
```

**Minor edit**

Slight correction to my original answer: since you called `SuspendBinding()` on the `BindingSource`, it would be more correct to say that changes to the `BindingSource` will not propogate to its datasource.

Comment: Wow, I have always thought SuspendBinding supressed the events to the control, not the other way around.  Apparently the method I need to use is: BindingSource.RaiseListChangedEvents.  Thank for the guidance.